# When importing styles into a React component, how do I assign a className that updates based off state?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, modular

I'm using style-loader to inject css modularly into my components ({style.exampleClassName}).

I want to display a loader for a set amount of time then display an image (at least 16 of these components in a grid pattern).

My current component looks like this:

```js
// Child Component

/**
*
* Sets up props for the child (icon)
*
*/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './styles.css';

class Child extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hidden : "shown",
      loading: "loading"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    const wait = this.props.wait;

    console.log('mounted');
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timeout working ' + wait);
      self.setState({
        hidden: "hidden",
        loading: "loaded"
      });
    }, wait);
  }


  render() {

    const hidden = `styles.${this.state.hidden}`;
    const loading = `styles.${this.state.loading}`;

      return (
        <div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./app/components/socialgrid/styles.css" />
          <div className={this.state.hidden}>
              <p>Loading...</p>
          </div>
          <div className={this.state.loading}>
              <p>Child - {this.props.wait}ms</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
  }

};

export default Child;


// Parent

/**
*
* Individual Icon Component
*
*/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import cx from 'classnames';
import Img from 'components/Img';
import Child from './Child';

// import Fb from './Fb.png';

class IndIcon extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
     <Child wait={1000} />
     <Child wait={5000} />
     <Child wait={4000} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
};


export default IndIcon;
```

```css
.hidden,
.loading{
  display: none;
}
```

Normally my styles would inject themselves by className={styles.exampleClassName} but here I'm running into the issue of the class not being injected because the class changes based of state (as I said above, just trying different wording to be clear).

I want to assign more than just the display:none element so I do need classes on these components.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You were not too far off... you just weren't passing your const variables into your JSX. Try modifying your render function as follows (amendments highlighted with bold):

```
render() {
    const hidden = `styles.${this.state.hidden}`;
    const loading = `styles.${this.state.loading}`;

      return (
        <div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./app/components/socialgrid/styles.css" />
          <div className={hidden}>
              <p>Loading...</p>
          </div>
          <div className={loading}>
              <p>Child - {this.props.wait}ms
          </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
```

*N.B.
Including your styles within the component in this way pollutes the global CSS namespace which can cause problems if you have styles if the same name defined elsewhere in the application ( by yourself or by another developer) which can give rise to unpredictable style behaviour*

Comment: You're adding extra processing by doing the `styles.${this.state.hidden}`. You can just use `<div className={this.state.hidden}>` in the JSX.

Comment: Yes, I tried but it doesn't pull in the styles.css link to the page, so though it does function the way I want it to by updating styles based on state, it doesn't actually apply the styles because this is modular. (That was poorly groomed code I posted. Sorry about that.) Thanks for getting back to me though. I wish that way worked!

Answer (score 0):

Even though I really wanted to update those classes on state change, I went this route instead and its way better:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Spinner from './Spinner';
import Icon from './Icon';

class Child extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
   super(props);

    this.state = {
     loading: true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const wait = this.props.wait;

   setTimeout(() => {
     this.setState({
        loading: false
      })
    }, wait)
  }

  render() {

    let content = this.state.loading ?
    <div><Spinner /></div> :
    <div><Icon /></div>;

    return (
     <div>{content}</div>
    )
  }

};
```

This way it loads components based off state change and a settimeout.